# Angular Material Slider Scaling Issues

Tags: angular-material

I have a material slider that I wanted to make thicker and longer so I am using the below CSS:

```
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-wrapper {
  top: 18px;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-wrapper {
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width:400px;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-background,
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill {
  height: 100%;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background-color: blue;
}
.mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px gray;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
}
.mat-slider-min-value:not(.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing) .mat-slider-thumb {
  background-color: white;
}
```

This does work and increase the width and length of the slider but when you start sliding it, about half way, the highlighted bar starts to pass where you actually are. I am not sure if this is a bug with Material or something I have to add in my CSS.

Comment: if u satisfy with this answer than voteup so other developer can easily find better solution

Answer (score 2):

No This is Not a bug

You can try to add this CSS to global style:

```
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-wrapper {
  top: 18px;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-wrapper {
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-background,
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill {
  height: 100%;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background-color: blue;
}
.mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px gray;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
}
.mat-slider-min-value:not(.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing) .mat-slider-thumb {
  background-color: white;
}
```

You can preview code here [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbtsy3?file=styles.css)

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: not putted class in ur css `.mat-slider-wrapper` and  `top:18px`

Comment: Sorry, I had that line in my CSS...forgot to add it to the question. I still have the same issue.

Comment: share ur stackblitz code if not then make a stackblitz

Comment: you took away my width: 400px as well. If you add that line back to your stackblitz you will see the issue with the slider.